# Open specific ViewController from push notification

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

On my xcode project I have a some views and a tab bar controller. When I open my app the first view comes up. I have also a server that sends to the app some push notifications.

I use on `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);

     }
}
```

My question is: how can I open a specific view (in this case is called "`AnswerDetailsVC`") when I open the notification? The specific view is opened from the 4th view on the tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you detect your push notifications payload is the right one to open the `AnswerDetailsVC`, just set selected tab of tabbar like this:

```
//  Open 4th tab in tabbar
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
```

Edit:
You can access controller at given tab and call any public method you want. So you can call button action manually or prepare public method which makes what you want to do after the notification and call it when you receive notification

Example code:

```
//  Get controller at given tab
AnswerDetailsVC *myController = (AnswerDetailsVC *)[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
//  Call button action or whatever public method you want
[myController buttonAction:nil];
```

Comment: mmm it's not what i mean. on 4th view I have a button that opens the "AnswerDetailsVC". So i don't need to open the 4th view, i need to open the AnswerDetailsVC directly.

Comment: See my edited answer. You questions was not much clear, so I didnt know what exactly you need to do